# What are the chances of US to UK flights being cancelled in the next 2 weeks?

Tags: usa, uk, air-travel, covid-19

I am travelling from London to San Francisco this coming Wednesday, and returning 10 days later. Although it looks like I may be able to get outgoing flight, I do not want to be stuck in the US indefinitely due to the Corona virus restrictions

(1) Are there are estimates as to whether the UK would cancel flights from the US before then?
(2) If a government will cancel flights due to these reasons, how much advance warning are they likely to give?
(3) If the US cancelled flights from the UK, would that also effect return flights to the UK?
(4) How easy do you think it would be to move back my departure date by a few days?

(For reference: At time of posting this there are ~800 confirmed cases of COVID-19 in the UK, and the growth rate daily has been exponential at about 1.4, so number of estimated cases on departure date are ~4,300, and ~90,000 by original departure date, if these growth rates continue).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this site or anybody in the world (maybe Chuck Norris) has the answer.

Comment: You'd need to be able to read the mind of Trump in order to answer that question.  Right now almost anything could happen.

Comment: At yesterday’s press conference the U.K. Prime Minister and his scientific advisers appeared to make it clear they do not support travel bans. The US stance appears to be hardening towards the UK https://amp.theguardian.com/world/live/2020/mar/13/coronavirus-live-updates-uk-us-australia-italy-europe-school-shutdown-share-markets-sport-events-cancelled-latest-update-news Whi knows?

Comment: In a like, but shorter distance, case I have decided not to travel. Is it worth the risk? My answer was 'no'. You might have more need to go.

Comment: As an example, Lufthansa has vastly reduced the number of flights going between the EU and the USA, but some are still going. So I’d expect that you would be able to return to the U.K. but possibly with a detour, say Boston-NewYork-London-Manchester instead of Boston-Manchester (just an example).

Comment: However, if you booked a flight to the USA today you might not be allowed to board in a week.